# ADO.NET - Data Adapter Fill Method - Fill Dataset with rows modified in SQL

Tags: datatable, ado.net, dataset, sqldataadapter, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using ADO.NET with Data Adaptor to Fill a Dataset in my .NET Core 3.1 Project.
The first run for the Fill method occurs when my program initially starts so I have an in memeory cache to start using with my business/program logic. When I then make any changes to the tables using EF Core, once the changes have been saved I then run the Data Adapter Fill method to re-populate the Dataset with the updates from the tables that were modified in SQL through EF Core..

Reading various docs for a number of days now, what I'm unclear about is whether the Data Adapter Fill method overwrites **all** of the existing table rows in the Dataset each time the fill method is called? i.e if I'm loading a dataset with a table from SQL that has 10k rows, is it going to overwrite all 10k rows that exist in the dataset, even if 99% of the rows have not changed?

The reason I am going down the Dataset route is that I want to keep and in memory cache of the various tables from SQL so I can query the data as fast as possible without raising queries SQL all the time.

The solution I want is something along the lines of Data Adaptor Fill method, but I don't want the Dataset to be overwritten for any rows that had not been modified  in SQL since the last run.

Is this how things are working already? or do I have to look for another solution?

Below just an example of the Adaptor Fill method.

```
public async Task<AdoNetResult> FillAlarmsDataSet()
    {
        string connectionString = _config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

        try
        {
            string cmdText1 = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Alarm] ORDER BY Id;" +
                "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[AlarmApplicationRole] ORDER BY Id;";

            dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdText1, connectionString);

            // Create table mappings
            dataAdapter.TableMappings.Add("Alarm", "Alarm");
            dataAdapter.TableMappings.Add("AlarmApplicationRole", "AlarmApplicationRole");

            alarmDataSet = new DataSet
            {
                Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
            };

            // Create and fill the DataSet
            await Task.Run(() => dataAdapter.Fill(alarmDataSet));

            return AdoNetResult.Success;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Return the task with details of the exception
            return AdoNetResult.Failed(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are using EF Core for Updates and Ado.Net to fill a dataset? Why are you mixing these technologies? If you would for example use Ado.Net for updates also there would be no need to re-fill the Dataset ...

Comment: Using ADO.Net across the board is not an option for me. What I want is a readonly list, table or whatever that can be queried as fast as possible. When a new item is changed or modified in SQL, i want this readonly list to be updated without having to re-load the whole list, as well as access for querying from multiple threads.

Comment: I may have to simply use a List with locks, but i'm partly unsure what happens when a function in a thread tries to access a locked object, does the function simply fail or wait for its turn to process?